# Collapsible input form with UITableView Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I need to make a collapsible tableView for an input form, I have searched a lot and for two days I'm trying different codes, but they don't fit my need and I don't know how to change them to what I want. I've found a couple of examples but they are just for showing an array of objects. what I need is a form like this picture, but not populating the cells with an array of Strings (Like so many tutorials that I found) but rather making the exact same thing as this screenshot but collapsible so that when for instance when I tap on `Personal info` it collapses.

This is one of the codes that I found online, but as I said I don't want to populate it with Array. I simply want to add as much Sections as I want with different cells and simply make them collapsible.

(and btw with this code my sections show collapsed but when I tap on each the app crashes)

> TestVC.swift

```
class TestVC: UITableViewController, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {

var sections = [
    Section(genre: "Animation", expanded: false),
    Section(genre: "Horror", expanded: false)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (sections[indexPath.section].expanded){
        return 44
    } else{
        return 0
    }
}


// Just to make it look nice
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = ExpandableHeaderView()
    header.customInit(title: sections[section].genre, section: section, delegate: self)
    return header
}

func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {
    sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    for i in 0..<6 {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}


}
```

> ExpandableHeaderView.swift

```
protocol ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {
    func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int)
}

class ExpandableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

var delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate?
var section: Int!

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderAction)))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func selectHeaderAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! ExpandableHeaderView
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: cell.section)
}

func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate){
    self.textLabel?.text = title
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
}



 }
```

(If there is other way than doing it with TableView that is also ok)

Thank you in advance for any help.

[image: this]

Comment: You can take button on header and after click on header just toggle the numberOfRows array count as 0.

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad how to I take button on header? could you please tell that?

Comment: Add button programmatically inside the viewForHeader Method

Comment: @AbedNaseri add `tap gesture` instead of `button` in header `UIView` you will `return`

Comment: @AbedNaseri  are u done??still having isssue??

Comment: @Ramesh not yet really, I'm a bit confused, thanks for asking

Comment: @AbedNaseri what  confussion ? show actual design   may be some one will  assist you in better way.

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry for late reply. my confusion is that I don't know how to tell which section should be collapsed. and I don't even know how to do it :D .
I have updated my question, with some codes.

Comment: @AbedNaseri what issue are u facing currently and can u show image coz u said  the image showen is a sample and what is the actual requirement and how mant cells will be there?

Comment: @Ramesh My first problem is that I'm not sure if I should do it with TableView or TableViewController. The second problem is for `viewForHeaderInSection` it returns UIView, I have no idea what to put there. and for Images that you asked, I haven't started the full Implementation because it's so many fields (and I don't want to make all inputs and then realise it is not possible to make it collapsible) I want to make it work then add them. but in each section there will be different input fields. E.g. in first section: 3 textField & 1 Switch and a DatePicker. in 2nd Section: 4 TextFields ...

Comment: @Ramesh There are more things such as ImagePicker or SelectField and so on

Comment: @Abed Naseri how many sections u have

Comment: @Ramesh 14 Sections, look , a colleague of mine who is not a app developer suggested a nice idea. He said put different input fields in one cell, so each section will have only one cell and that cell may contain all different inputFields, sounds interesting. 
So imagine now I only have 1 cell in each. now is the question of what to use (TableView or TableViewController) and how to collapse

Comment: @AbedNaseri  u can use any one of them  but If its like home controller or main conroller then Tableviewcontroller is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the idea a bit, added the fields to `stackviews` and when tapping on the first element of the `stackView` that is a `button`, I hide the elements inside the rest of `stackView`, this way it collapses.

```
for n in 1...myStackView.arrangedSubviews.count - 1{
    myStackView.arrangedSubviews[n].isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sections Header Can be clickable(add Button USE ViewForHeader Delegate method) and make one cell(desgin in storyboard ) from storyboard and take outlets for Name,lastName,city etc and change titles as per sections(In CellForRow) and reuse that cell for all sections with different tags 
finally  on click of section header change row height(Make Row Height Dynamic take a variable) to Close and Open.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just an example, it is not just textFields in the form, there will be Switches and checkboxes and ImagePicker ...

Comment: in that case  if  all cells are same u can design one cell and reuse or if u have different cells for eachsection you should try some thing else